# comparing values of int object and number does not work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am writing an application that takes a users input (from a UITextView) and then compares the input to a pre-defined value.
All inputs from the textfields are required to be numbers, so I use this code to convert the NSString into an int value when a button is pressed.

(age is the text view)

```
NSString *ageString = age.text;
int ageInt = [ageString intValue];
```

I then use this code to compare the text to a predefined list of numbers

```
if (ageInt > 12) {
    label1.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];}
else {
    label1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

When I run the application everything works and I get no errors, however, when I enter a value into the "age" textView that is larger than the pre-defined value (lets say 13) it still turns label 1 red.

So the summary of this problem is that when the value is being compared, it doesn't compare correctly. I'm curious if anyone knows why that is? Perhaps I am using the wrong classes?

Comment: What did the debugger say the value of `ageInt` is in your failing case?

Comment: Thats the odd thing, the debugger puts out no errors.
its just a matter that the code does no compare the two number values correctly.
I am curious if there is any input about what could be going on

Comment: I'm not asking about errors.  What does the debugger say the value of `ageInt` is?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, my mistake.
I used the NSLog (@"%d", ageInt) and it says that the age is whatever I enter (ex, 13 if I type 13 in the textview)

Comment: I didn't ask about logging.  What does the debugger say the value of `ageInt` is?

Comment: Im sorry once again,
same thing though, The debugger displays the correct variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog` `ageInt`:

```
NSLog(@"age.text: %s, ageInt: %d", age.text, ageInt);
```

right after:

```
int ageInt = [ageString intValue];
```

That should show the problem, that `ageInt` is not really > 12 and why.

If the `ageInt` is > 13 then either the color setting code is not being called or the color is being reset after the call.

Add some breakpoints in Xcode and insure the correct color setter being called--and the value of `ageInt` at that point.

Comment: I expect you're right. Logging after the read isn't the right place though - he should log where it's being used.  Or both, ideally.

Comment: I will keep running through it with the debugger and try to find the source of the problem,
but thank you I was just curious if I had done something wrong with my conversions or comparing 

Thank you all

Comment: fixed it! you were correct, I was re-setting the values somewhere in the code, not sure were but I am working on it. thank you!